# can't play DRM protected videos

Tags: windows, video, netflix, drm

I am unable to play any DRM protected video on my PC.

For example:

- Netflix on Firefox fails because of "Widevine CDM Plugin has crashed"
  [image]
- Netflix on Chrome fails because of this error https://help.netflix.com/en/node/27451 (the "Widevine CDM" component is up to date & "protectedContent" is allowed
- Netflix on Microsoft Edge fails because of error "Pardon the interruption. Sorry, we're having trouble with your request."
  [image]
- Netflix using Netflix app downloaded from Mictosoft store fails because of app crash when try to play video ("Whoops, something went wrong")
- HBOMAX on Chrome because "An error has occurred"
- ...

What have I tried:

- reinstall browsers
- disable HW acceleration in browser's setting
- windows update
- execute CMD "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth"
- execute CMD "sfc /scannow"
- download & install actual drivers (531.18) for my GPU (Nvidia GT 1030)
- after all these things, I have even tried to reinstall Windows 10 completely. no help.
- tried the different PC with same Netflix/HBOMAX account - worked
- tried watching DRM not-protected H265 4k video locally using VLC - worked

My PC:

- MB: Z87M-PLUS
- CPU: Intel Core i5 4670
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030
- RAM: 8GB
- Windows: Windows 10 Pro 64bit, 10.0.19044, Build 19044

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft Edge?

Comment: I have forgot about this browser. Tried it just now but doesn't work either.

Comment: What make and model is your monitor? How is it connected to your graphics card (DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort, …)? Does NVIDIA Control Panel show a successful HDCP connection?

Comment: In `chrome://components/`, search for the two `Widevine` plugins and click "Check for update". Continue with [this tutorial](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-Widevine-on-Chrome).

Comment: @DanielB I am using a Samsung 4K TV connected by HDMI. I have checked the HDCP status in NVIDIA Control Panel and no problems there. "Your graphics card and display are HDCP capable.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I have done the Widevine plugin check & update using Chrome. It says, that everything is up to date. Your tutorial is about "installing Widevine on Chrome", however this is not issue caused by Chrome.

Comment: There are more actions described in the tutorial.

Comment: Every action in that tutorial Chrome related. Apart from the antivirus check, but I don't use any third party antivirus - just the Windows Defender. Anyway I have tried the actions and no help.